# Is there any story where Ravana came to perform a Yagna for Lord Rama?

Tags: ramayana, rama, ravana

I read a story on a forum which is as follows:

> Rama needed a bridge to be built across the ocean to reach Lanka, in order to defeat Ravana. The night before they started their preparations, he decided to conduct a Yagna to worship Shiva at Rameshwaram. As he was going to fight one of his most powerful adversaries, he needed the most scholarly priest to conduct the Yagna for him. He was informed that Ravana himself is the most learned scholar of all times. An invitation was sent to Ravana, who accepted it, arrived at Rameshwaram and conducted a Yagna with all holy rites.
>
> Interestingly, the Yagna could be considered successfully completed only when Rama would sit with his wife Sita in the ceremony, who was held captive by Ravana in Lanka. Ravana not only brought Sita to the Yagna, he presided over the proper arrangements and completion of the Yagna.
>
> After the Yagna got over, Rama sought Ravana's blessings in defeating him, to which Ravana replied, Tathastu.

I have never came across this story and believe that this should not be in Valmiki's Ramayana. I wanted to check whether this story is authentic or not and which scripture contains this story.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely not in the Valmiki Ramayana.  And I highly doubt that it happened.

Comment: The incident is not found in Kamba Ramayana (tamil ramayana) written in 8-9th century nor in Ramacharitamanas, also. The ideal base for Ramayana is Valmiki Ramayana followed by Kamba Ramayana. The remaining ramayanas contains lot of fantacies added the respective authors to leave their own stamp on the story...

Comment: e.g. i saw a the strange story like Ram and Lakshmana approched Ravana for knowledge when Ravana was dying  on a web site of devdutt patnaik who writes so many things but never provided the proof from where this story is picked up...There are too many folk lores based on Ramayana..These are mere folk lores and have no base in Puranas also..All these are not true. Valmiki Ramayana and Kamba Ramayana are the best in the class.

Comment: @Krishna Well, in addition to the Valmiki Ramayana there is also the version of the Ramayana found in the Padma Purana, and the Adhyatma Ramayana found in the Brahmanda Ramayana.  But yeah, I agree with you that a lot of supposed stories concerning Rama are fake.

Comment: @Keshav- Yes, i agree, that padma purana or for that many of 18 puranas have valid information about Ramayana...But, if there is any conflict we need to refer to main source which is Valmiki Ramayana which is the best and Kamba Ramayana being the second though this was written in 9-10 th century.

Comment: this is a part of ramcharitra manas by goswami tulsi dasji

Comment: These stories are all false

Comment: Well agree stories can be fake but than ramayan itself can also be false, so I think just this assumption that it is not in Valmiki Ramayan doesnt make it Fake and false , as we know many stories were kept alive by oral or street drama plays,

 Also some of the writers were devotee so they can know some stuff by meditation magical powers :D

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Q&A where Sri Sri Ravi Shankar talks about this story mentioned in the Adhyatma Ramayana:

> "...Lord Rama wanted to do be victorious in battle against Ravana, and
>   for that He wanted to establish a Shivalinga and worship it. Now to do
>   this, a priest was needed, but in those days there were no priests
>   found in Rameshwaram. So Lord Rama was in dire need of a good priest
>   to perform the rituals.
>
> Ravana was a staunch devotee of Lord Shiva and was also a Brahmin by
>   birth. So Ravana’s brother Vibhishana (who was on Lord Rama’s side),
>   told Lord Rama that Ravana was very well-versed in the rituals. So
>   Lord Rama sent an invitation to Ravana to come and preside as the
>   priest for the pooja at Rameshwaram.
>
> Ravana accepted the invitation and came. But then he told Lord Rama
>   that the pooja would be incomplete without his wife being present. No
>   pooja or yagna can be performed without the wife’s presence. So he
>   told Lord Rama, ‘Since you are a married man, both you and your wife
>   have to sit together for the pooja, otherwise you cannot perform the
>   pooja’.
>
> Then Lord Rama said to him, ‘It is the duty of the priest to provide
>   an alternative for anything that is missing. Since my wife is not with
>   me (having been kept in captivity by Ravana at that time), please tell
>   me what the alternative for this problem is. Can we keep a doll in her
>   place as a substitute?’
>
> Then Ravana said, ‘I do not believe in alternative. I would want
>   everything to be present for the worship of Lord Shiva. So I will call
>   your wife here for the pooja. After the pooja, please send her back to
>   Lanka’.
>
> So Ravana brings Sita for the pooja. After the pooja, when Lord Rama
>   and Sita bow down to touch the feet of the priest, that is, Ravana, to
>   take blessings, then Ravana blesses Lord Rama by saying ‘Vijayi
>   bhavaha’ (May victory be yours!). He had no choice but to do so.
>
> When someone touches the feet of a priest, he is left with no choice
>   but to bless that person. So Ravana had to give that blessing to Lord
>   Rama for which He had organized the pooja. He also blessed Sita by
>   saying ‘Sumangali bhavaha’ (May you receive all that is best and
>   auspicious always!) Such was Ravana’s magnanimity. After blessing both
>   of them, Ravana took Sita back to Lanka with him.
>
> This is a very exciting story. We always perceive Ravana as a villain,
>   but even Ravana had many good qualities in him. This is why when
>   Ravana was counting his last breaths and was at his death bed on the
>   battlefield, Lord Rama told Lakshmana to go and touch the feet of
>   Ravana and receive knowledge from him as he lay dying on the
>   battlefield. Lord Rama said, ‘If I go to him (Ravana) then he will
>   leave his body and his soul will merge into Me. So before that
>   happens, go and learn all that you can from him’.
>
> Do you know, there is a Gita by the name Ravana? It is called Ravana
>   Gita.
>
> Of the five Gitas that are present, it is one of them. Just like you
>   have the Srimad Bhagavad Gita, Ashtavakra Gita, Udhhava Gita, and Guru
>   Gita; there is another Gita called Ravana Gita (the song of Ravana).
>   In it, Ravana teaches many sermons to Lakshmana..."

You can read the full article here:
http://www.artofliving.org/wisdom-q-a-15-may-2013-qa-2

Comment: Ramayana means valmiki only not any other

Comment: I can't find the story from Adhyatma Ramayana.

Comment: @Pandya: When you for yourself state that this story is not  from Adhyatma Ramayana, then why was this answer allowed to remain?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv becuse wrong answers should not be deleted. Read [this explanation](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/678/277).